# ADF - trigger pipe 2 on pipe 1 successful completion

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-eventgrid, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to chain 2 ADF pipelines together. If pipeline 1 runs successfully, I want to trigger pipeline 2.

Please note that pipeline 1 has a schedule based trigger and I dont want to create another pipeline where I combine pipeline 1 and 2.

In AWS we have something called cloudwatch events/rules that takes care of this requirement. Is there something similar in Azure? If not, what are my options?

Please note that I don't want to create a wrapper pipeline that will perform an execute activity to execute 1 and 2 as I want to decouple them entirely

Comment: compounding to my answer, checkout this similar setup [tutorial](https://youtu.be/FpKrBLeqdj4)

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really the only current way to do this:

Create a pipeline that executes other pipelines in sequence. Then setup the trigger to run on this one. [image: RunAll]

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box feature to achieve this, you can share your idea [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)

What you can do is something as below.

1. On the first schedule based triggered pipeline (**pipeline 1**), just have a [`WebActivity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) at the end which would signal to a [custom event created using event hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-topics) (send event to custom event grid topic endpoint).
2. Acting on the previous event signal use a [Create a custom event trigger to run a pipeline in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-custom-event-trigger) i.e. the **pipeline 2**